# ASP.Net MVC 4.0 - Validation Issues With array based properties on ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

**ASP.Net MVC 4.0 - Validation Issues With array based properties on ViewModel .**

Scenario : 
When a ViewModel has a string array as a property type,the default Scaffolding template for say, Edit, does not render the that property in the markup.

Say, I have ViewModel setup like this :

**Employee.cs**

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Required]
        public int EmpID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string LastName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string[] Skills
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

The (strongly typed) Edit View  generated by the  scaffolding template, as shown below, typically skips the portion relevant to field Skills.

```
**Employee.cshtml**

@model StringArray.Models.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditEmployee";
}

<h2>EditEmployee</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmpID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The corresponding Controller code is

```
..
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditEmployee()
        {
            Employee E = new Employee()
            {
                EmpID = 1,
                FirstName = "Sandy",
                LastName = "Peterson",
                Skills = new string[] { "Technology", "Management", "Sports" }
            };

            return View(E);
        }

            [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditEmployee(Employee E)
        {

            return View(E);
        }
```

To get the missing section for the Skills field, I added

- Snippet to the View

  ```
      <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Skills)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Skills)
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills)
     </div>
  ```
- Corresponding UIHint to the ViewModel

  [UIHint("String[]")]
  public string[] Skills      ...
- EditorTemplates inside relevant folder as 
                      ~\View\shared\EditorTemplates\String[].cshtml 
  and
                      ~\View\shared\EditorTemplates\mystring.cshtml

  **string[].cshtml**

  ```
  @model System.String[]
  @if(Model != null && Model.Any()) 
  {  
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Length; i++)
  {

      @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i], "mystring")
      //Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i])
  }
  }
  ```

  **mystring.cshtml**

  ```
   @model System.String
              @{
                  //if(Model != null)
                  {
                   //To resolve issue/bug with extra dot getting rendered in the name - like 
                       //Skills.[0], Skills.[1], etc.
                     //ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix=ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix.Replace(".[", "[");

                      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
                  }
              }
  ```

But despite this all, the Validations for the Skills section [with 3 fields/elements  - refer the EditEmployee method in Controller above.]
        are entirely skipped, on postback.

I tried below changes inside the mystring.cshtml EditorTemplate :

```
//to correct the rendered names in the browser from Skills.[0] to Skills for all the 3 items in the 
//Skills (string array), so that model binding works correctly.
string x = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
x = x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf("."));

@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model, new { Name = x })
```

Postback WORKS But Validations DON'T, since the "**data-valmsg-for**" still points to *`<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Skills" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`*
and thus doesn't apply at granular level - string element level.

Lastly, I tried removing  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills) from the Employee.cshtml and correspondingly adding the
same to string[].cshtml as  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i]). 
But this led to  data-valmsg-for getting rendered for each granular string element like

data-valmsg-for="Skills.[0]" , 
data-valmsg-for="Skills.[1]" and data-valmsg-for="Skills.[2]", respectively.

**Note: Validations work for other fields - EmpID, FirstName  LastName, BUT NOT for Skills.**

**Question**
How do I set the data-valmsg-for="Skills" for each of the above three granular elements related to Skills property.

I am stuck on this for quite some time now. It would be nice if some one can point out the issue, at the earliest.

Thanks, Sandesh L

Answer (score 1):

This is where you like to change

```
   [Required]
    public string[] Skills
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

You are giving validation on the array.

you might want to have a new string class call Skill

```
[Required]
public string Skill
{
            get;
            set;
}
```

And you can change to you model with

```
    [Required]
    public List<Skill> Skills
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I prefer using List instead of array. Then, you can change you skill view according to the model updated

you template view can be something like

```
@model IEnumerable<Skill>

<div class="editor-label">
 <h3>@Html.LabelFor(model=> model.Skills)
</h3> 
</div> 

<div class="editor-field"> 
@foreach (var item in Model)
 { @Html.Label(model => item) 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item) <br/> 
} 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item)
```

Comment: Trying out your suggestion, with corresponding chnage to the View like : <div class="editor-label">      
   <h3>@Html.LabelFor(model=> model.Skills)</h3>
  </div>
    
  <div class="editor-field">      
    @for(int i =0; i < ((List<StringArray.Models.Skill>)(Model.Skills)).Count; i++)
    {         
   @Html.Label(Model.Skills[i].ToString())
   @Html.TextBox("skill", Model.Skills[i].SkillName}) 
   <br />
    }
      
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills), causes Skill to be null on postback :(.

Comment: Sandesh Lohar, make sure you are posting back your Employee model to your controller. I was having the same problem as you where the array would never be valid, but what Miller said is correct. You need to create a new model specific for handling required on the skill itself not the array.